# Exception while adding database tables for magento

Tags: database, magento

I'm creating my module on magento 1.6.2.0 with WAMP server;
when I try to add my tables to the magento database theres an exception, and in the Mysql page my tables a not created but I found the name of my module with  under the table "core_ressource" ;
can you help me please ?

This is my PHP upgrade page:

```
<?php


    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();
    /**
     * Create table 'interactivebanner/interactivebanner'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner'))
        ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
            ), 'Entity Id')
        ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,100, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '',
            ), 'Name')
        ->addColumn('link', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,255, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '',
            ), 'Link')
        ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Status');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

     /**
     * Create table 'interactivebanner/interactivebannerprod'
     */
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebannerprod'))
        ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
            ), 'Value ID')
        ->addColumn('tag_content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '',
            ), 'Status id')
        ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
             ), 'Entity Id')
        ->addColumn('position_v', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,10, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Position V')
        ->addColumn('position_h', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,10, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            ), 'Position H')
        ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('interactivebanner/interactivebanner', 'entity_id', 'interactivebanner/interactivebannerprod', 'entity_id'),
            'entity_id', $installer->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebannerprod'), 'entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE);
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

  $installer->endSetup();
```

and this is  the exception:

```
Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php on line 230
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php
    [line:protected] => 245
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php
                    [line] => 230
                    [function] => mageCoreErrorHandler
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8
                            [1] => Trying to get property of non-object
                            [2] => C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php
                            [3] => 230
                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [model] => Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Resource
                                    [entity] => interactivebanner
                                    [modelsNode] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                        (
                                            [varien] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                (
                                                    [class] => Varien
                                                )

                                            [core] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                (
                                                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model
                                                    [resourceModel] => core_resource
                                                )

                                            [core_resource] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                (
                                                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource
                                                    [deprecatedNode] => core_mysql4
                                                    [entities] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                        (
                                                            [config_data] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_config_data
                                                                )

                                                            [website] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_website
                                                                )

                                                            [store] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_store
                                                                )

                                                            [resource] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_resource
                                                                )

                                                            [cache] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_cache
                                                                )

                                                            [cache_tag] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_cache_tag
                                                                )

                                                            [cache_option] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_cache_option
                                                                )

                                                            [store_group] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_store_group
                                                                )

                                                            [config_field] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_config_field
                                                                )

                                                            [email_template] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_email_template
                                                                )

                                                            [variable] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_variable
                                                                )

                                                            [variable_value] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_variable_value
                                                                )

                                                            [translate] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_translate
                                                                )

                                                            [session] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_session
                                                                )

                                                            [layout_update] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_layout_update
                                                                )

                                                            [layout_link] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] => core_layout_link
                                                                )

                                                            [url_rewrite] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [table] =>  ...
```

this is a part of  my config.xml

```
    <models>
        <interactivebanner>
            <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Resource</resourceModel>
        </interactivebanner>
        <interactivebanner_resource>
            <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <interactivebanner>
                    <table>interactivebanner</table>
                </interactivebanner>
                <interactivebannerprod>
                    <table>interactivebannerprod</table>
                </interactivebannerprod>
            </entities>
        </interactivebanner_resource>
    </models>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was in the config.xml file :

```
<interactivebanner>
<class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model</class>
<resourceModel>interactivebanner_resource</resourceModel>
</interactivebanner>
```

instead of :

```
<interactivebanner>
<class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model</class>
<resourceModel>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Resource</resourceModel>
</interactivebanner>
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that in config.xml to declare the table like this:

```
<module_mysql4>
 <class>Company_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <custom_model_name>
                        <table>table_name</table>
                    </custom_model_name>
                </entities>
</module_mysql4>
```

Comment: Try to change interactivebanner_resource with interactivebanner_mysql4. and <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model_Resource</class>
with <class>Kiwi_InteractiveBanner_Model_Mysql4</class> . See this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Comment: But my folder name is Kiwi/Interactivebanner/Model/Resource !

Comment: Do you have this structure  ? http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/custom_module_with_custom_database_table . you must declare Kiwi/Interactivebanner/Model/Mysql4 and there, your collection .

Comment: Block/****
    controllers/****
    etc/****
    Model/
        Resource/
            Interactivebanner/****
    sql/
        Interactivebanner_setup/****

Comment: See this instead: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources . Your Model/Resource should be Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup .

Comment: the module structure is right, i'm sure about it, because if it wasn't, magento will not be able to  access and run  the php upgrade/setup file.[\n]
i've just puted a "die('mag');" in the begening of the upgrade file and i start movin it down in the file, when i put it after [code]        ->newTable($installer->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner'))
[/code] i get the exception !!

Comment: Tarek, you're not listening to people... all of the XML and class structure above is correct but for install files must be here: c:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\local\Kiwi\Interactivebanner\Model\Resource\Mysql4\Setup

Answer (score -1):

Use Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup instead of Model/ Resource/ Interactivebanner . See the next tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Comment: the module structure is right, i'm sure about it, because if it wasn't, magento will not be able to access and run the php upgrade/setup file.[\n] i've just puted a "die('mag');" in the begening of the upgrade file and i start movin it down in the file, when i put it after `->newTable($installer->getTable('interactivebanner/interactivebanner'))` i get the exception !!